# Выход из нескольких циклов

Tags: python, циклы

Есть входной список, элементы которого состоят из некого текста. Нужно проверить, есть ли в элементах списка слова из одного списка и из другого, и если есть слова из одного, и нет из другого, то вывести некое сообщение.
Не получается завершить несколько циклов после получения результата и перейти к следующему элементу списка

```
some_text = ['some text','another text','one more']
whitelist = ['another','more']
blacklist = ['some','else']
for text in some_text:
    for items in blacklist:
        if text.find(items) != -1:
            for item in whitelist:
                if text.find(item) == -1:
                    print('Found!')
                else:
                    print('Not found')
```

Также прошу простить за возможные ошибки или опечатки в коде.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Можно ли прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523517/23044)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Вариант первый, некрасивый**

Для выхода из цикла до его нормального завершения в Python используется оператор `break`:

```
for item in items:
    if some_condition:
        break
```

Для того, чтобы выйти из нескольких циклов по условию, выполнившемуся во внутреннем цикле, используется флаг выхода - переменная, которая изначально имеет значение `False`, а при необходимости выйти из цикла преждевременно принимает значение `True`:

```
flag = False
for outer in outer_list:
    for inner in inner_list:
        if some_condition:
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
```

Таким образом можно выйти из любого количества вложенных циклов, нужно лишь добавлять проверку на флаг выхода в конец каждого.

**Вариант второй, красивый**

Вам стоит немного поменять структуру вашего кода. Для начала вынесите проверки на вхожденения слов из `blacklist` и `whitelist` в отдельную функцию:

```
def contains_words(text, words_list):
    for word in words_list:
        if text.find(word) != -1:
            return True
    return False
```

Теперь проверка на вхождение слов из `whitelist` и невхождение слов из `blacklist` будет выглядеть так:

```
for text in some_text:
    if contains_words(text, whitelist) and not contains_words(text, blacklist):
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

Если выражение `contains_words(text, whitelist)` вернёт `False`, Python не станет вычислять значение выражения `not contains_words(text, blacklist)`, так как, каким бы оно ни было, значение выражения `contains_words(text, whitelist) and not contains_words(text_blacklist)` всегда будет `False`.

Переписав код таким образом вы сохраните изначально задуманную функциональность, при этом значительно повысив читаемость кода и упростив возможные изменения в будущем.

http://ideone.com/bOO2RM

Comment: Если использовать конструкцию `for ... else ...`, то можно избавиться от переменной `flag` в первом случае, правда, придётся обратить условие во вложенном цикле

Answer (score 1):

Вот `goto` для выхода из нескольких циклов пришёлся бы кстати, делал так на PHP, по коду всё понятно и очевидно, и красивее, чем с флагами

Comment: https://tproger.ru/links/python-goto/