# Можно ли прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции, возможно ли это?
Такой код:

```
def func():
    if True:
        break
while True:
    func()
```

Естественно не работает.
Можно заменить на:

```
def func():
    if True:
        return True
while True:
    if func():
        break
```

но это добавляет "лишнюю" проверку в цикл, что нежелательно.

Можно отказаться от использования функции, и просто копировать код с break, но это превратит все в нечитаемую кашу. Есть ли еще варианты?

---

Добавлено:

очень примерно код выглядит так: (он, конечно, больше, но я не знаю, что еще может быть важно)

```
def func(p1,p2,p3):
    answer = api(p1,p2,p3)
    if answer['ответ'] == не_устраивающие_нас_значение:
        break
while True:
    #что-то считаем
    if что-то-там:
        #еще что-то считаем
        if еще-что-то:
            func(p1,p2,p3)
```

Comment: можно, а как, зависит от вашего кода (решение для одного случая может быть не подходящим для другого). Приведите более реалистичный (минимальный) пример

Comment: @jfs
Спасибо за ответ. Я не очень понял, что вы хотите увидеть, в моем случае все выглядит примерно так, сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: @jfs
Готово.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере возврат из функции выйти/не выйти статуса работает:

```
if "еще-что-то" and not keep_doing_it(p1,p2,p3):
    break
```

где функция `keep_doing_it(*p)` возвращает `False`, если цикл прекратить надо.

В общем случае, если из-за ошибки необходимо цикл остановить, то можно исключение выбросить, например, `raise TimeoutError("X takes too long")`.

Если  вообще работу хочется завершить, то можно `sys.exit("reason")` вызывать.

Зависит от функции, где `exit()` разместить, возможно совместить: одна функция выбрасывает подходящую ошибку, а код выше по стеку уже может `exit()` вызвать при обработке ошибки, если ошибка неисправимая.

В отдельных случаях, когда функция тесно связана с циклом и сам цикл внутри генератора, то можно `raise StopIteration` выбросить, как это функция `next()` делает. Хотя [в новом коде рекомендуется ловить StopIteration и использовать явный `return` в генераторе](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/). Поэтому может быть проще просто Boolean статус вернуть.

Если генератор передан как явный объект, то можно [такие методы как `.throw()`,  `.close()` метод вызвать](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), чтобы генератор преждевременно остановить из кооперирующей функции. Но такие вещи редко нужно делать. Они полезны, чтобы более высокого уровня функциональность реализовать, а не для прямого использования.

Comment: 1. Красивое и интересное решение, правда добавляет "лишнее" логическое умножение в цикл, что наверное лучше, чем лишний if, но все же.
2. Про исключения, я не в курсе, тот же вопрос: использование try except занимает или нет дополнительное процессорное время в цикле?
3. exit() подходит идеально, без лишней нагрузки, но естественно, вариант не на каждый случай.

Про генераторы - не мой случай, но уверен, будут очень полезны пользователям из гугла :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно кинуть исключение, а в верхней функции его поймать. Так делать не очень хорошо идеологически, если ситуация "значение не понравилась" вполне адекватная - исключения всё-таки предназначены для *исключительных* ситуаций, в которых требуется прервать исполнение кода немедленно, так как дальнейшие действия бессмысленны.

Примеры ситуаций, в которых я бы стал использовать исключение: сервер недоступен, авторизация не удалась, пользователя забанили. В которых не стал бы: вычисление завершилось с результатом `true` (а мы искали как раз первый `true`).

Comment: Использование try except занимает или нет дополнительное процессорное время в цикле? Если нет, то это вполне подходящий вариант.

Comment: @AAA насколько я знаю, наличие try/catch времени почти не требует, а вот поймать исключение - это относительно долго.

Comment: То есть по сравнению с простой if конструкцией - преимущество особого не дает? В любом случае спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def func():
    print("Call func")
    setattr(func2, "flag", 0)  # если нужно прервать цикл


def func2():
    func2.flag = 1

    try:
        while True:
            assert func2.flag
            func()
    except AssertionError:
        # ваш дальнейший код
        print("Выход из цикла")

func2()
```

И ловите AssertionError!

Comment: Использование try except занимает или нет дополнительное процессорное время в цикле? А assert?

Comment: Вы бы еще спросили, сколько времни занимает вызов функции!? Вы вкурсе, что вызов функции - это очень затратная по времени операция?

Comment: А и я думал где-нибудь такое спросить. Предполагал, но не был в курсе. Так что спасибо и за это :)