# Python - как прервать выполнение функции из другой функции?

Tags: python

Вопрос - как я могу описать такую вещь - есть функция выполняющая определенные действия, внутри нее я вызываю вторую функцию, в которую я передаю функцию-родитель и внутри второй функции я должен исходя из определенных условий либо продолжить выполнение функции-родителя, либо прервать ее выполнение. Возможно ли такое реализовать и, если возможно, то как?

Comment: Описали странное желание (и мне кажется я даже до конца и не понял), мб просто кинуть исключение?

Comment: Опишите какую проблему пытаетесь решить с помощью прерывания (какой контекст)? [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Можно ли прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523517/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможные варианты:

#### Выбросте исключение

(то что предложил jfs)

```python
def child_func():
    if something_went_wrong:
       raise Exception("Something went wrong")
    
def parent_func():
   # ...
   try:
      child_func()
   except Exception as e:
      print("Error:", e)
      return
   # ...
```

Можно исключение не обрабатывать, если это уместно и не повредит работе (мало ли, может при не выполнении некоего условия вы хотите, что бы все "легло")

#### Верните bool

```python
def child_func():
    if something_went_wrong:
       return False
    # ...
    return True
    
def parent_func():
   # ...
   result = child_func()
   if result:
      print("Something went wrong")
      return
   # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы продолжить выполнение родительской функции, выполните `return` в дочерней функции.

Чтобы прервать выполнение родительской функции, выбросите исключение. Например:

```
if i < 0 or i >= len(self):
    raise IndexError("index out of range")
```