# Как остановить оператор if в функции def. Python

Tags: python

Предупреждаю, возможно мой вопрос поставлен неправильно, учусь. Не могу определить ошибку.

"break" outside loop. Не пойму в чем дело, он же находится в условии  " if " . Если я правильно понимаю, то после ввода "Да", цикл while должен начаться повторно, после ввода "Нет" должен исполнится оператор break. Приложил весь код. Помогите!

```
# простейший калькулятор, 1й блок while, будет выполнятся до тех пор, пока не напишем "quit"
while True:
    print("Кулькулитор 1.0 by Sedoy")
    print("Введите 'плюс' чтобы сложить 2 числа")
    print("Введите 'минус' чтобы вычесть 2 числа")
    print("Введите 'умножить' чтобы умножить 2 числа")
    print("Введите 'делить' чтобы делить 2 числа")
    print("Введите 'остаток' чтобы узнать остаток от деления 2х чисел")
    print("Введите 'выход' чтобы покинуть программу")
    а = input('И что мы ждем? Пиши уже че-нить: ') # русская а
    if а == "выход":
        print('Покинуть корабль, покинуть корабль!!!!!')
        print('Только крысы бегут с корабля!')
        break
    elif а == "я одмен":
        admin = input("Да что вы говорите? Введите имя вашей правой руки: ")
        if (admin != "Люся" and admin != "люся"): #банальная проверка по имени руки (*-__-*)
            print("Добро пожаловать о великий!")
            boom = input("Ждем ваших приказаний, хозяин - ")
            if boom != 'рябчиков с ананасами': #увы данную волю исполнить невозможно(   хнык ;(
                print("Склоняюсь перед вашей волей")
            else:
                print('Иш чего, щегол. А ключи от квартиры где деньги лежат тебе не надобно? Бегом изучать кулькулитор')
        else:
            print("Жалкий глупец, да как ты смеешь порочить имя Великой руки??????")
        def возврат():
            возврат1 = input("Я гляжу ты попался, выхода нет. Калькулятор ннада? Отвечай Да или Нет : ")
            if возврат1 == 'Да':  # не получается на данный момент осуществить остановку программы через данный оператор
                return True
            else:
                print('Осуществляем выход из программы')
                break   #не работоспособный            
        возврат()
    elif а == "плюс":
        число1 = float(input("Введите 1ое число: "))
        число2 = float(input("Введите 2ое число: "))
        результат = str(число1 + число2) #делаем как строку, хpen знает зачем
        print('Результат: ' + результат)
    elif а == "минус":
        число1 = float(input("Введите 1ое число: "))
        число2 = float(input("Введите 2ое число: "))
        результат = str(число1 + число2) #делаем как строку, х знает зачем
        print('Результат: ' - результат)
    elif а == "умножить":
        число1 = float(input("Введите 1ое число: "))
        число2 = float(input("Введите 2ое число: "))
        результат = str(число1 * число2) #делаем как строку, х знает зачем
        print('Результат: ' + результат)
    elif а == "делить":
        число1 = float(input("Введите 1ое число: "))
        число2 = float(input("Введите 2ое число: "))
        результат = str(число1 / число2) #делаем как строку, х знает зачем
        print('Результат: ' + результат)
    elif а == "остаток":
        число1 = float(input("Введите 1ое число: "))
        число2 = float(input("Введите 2ое число: "))
        результат = str(число1 % число2) #делаем как строку, х знает зачем
        print('Результат: ' + результат)
    else:
        print("Пожалуйста, прочитай условие кулькулитора!")
```

Comment: функция возврат ничего не знает про внешний цикл..

Comment: Если сделать `return False`, а вызов завернуть в if, можно будет вызвать break снаружи функции `возврат`

Comment: не совсем понимаю про "вызов завернуть в if", как это изобрать в коде?

Comment: В чем суть функции, которая определенна в цикле?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Можно ли прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523517/23044)

Answer (score 1):

> функция возврат ничего не знает про внешний цикл..
>   Если сделать return False, а вызов завернуть в if, можно будет вызвать break снаружи функции возврат

```
def возврат():
    возврат1 = input("Я гляжу ты попался, выхода нет. Калькулятор ннада? Отвечай Да или Нет : ")
    if возврат1 == 'Да':  # не получается на данный момент осуществить остановку программы через данный оператор
        return True
    else:
        print('Осуществляем выход из программы')
        return False     
if not возврат():
    break
```

Comment: Ответ направлен только на решение конкретной проблемы("break" outside loop).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.