# Прервать (break) внешний (средний) вложенный цикл for в цикле

Tags: python, циклы

Доброго времени суток! Возникла заминка с циклами в питоне. Суть задачи в том, чтоб при нахождении определенного значения в списке "c", список "a" переходил на следующею итерацию, а списки "b" и "c" обнулялись. Не могу понять как такое провернуть с циклом с двойным вложением.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        for q in c:
            if q == 400:
                pass
            print(i, j, q)
```

Если цикл с одним вложением - все очень просто. Помогает инструкция брейк, цикл "b" завершается и наступает переход к следующей итерации цикла "a":

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if j == 40:
            break
        print(i, j)
```

а как быть в первом случае?

Comment: В других языках можно `break middle` (break с label) использовать, [например, в Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements)

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Как выйти из цикла python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549989/23044), [Можно ли прервать цикл, находясь внутри функции?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523517/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Выход из нескольких циклов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432654/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно завернуть два внутренних цикла в функцию, и при достижении нужного значения завершать её через return.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]


def inner(i):
    for j in b:
        for q in c:
            if q == 400:
                return None
            print(i, j, q)

for i in a:
    inner(i)
```

Comment: Можно использовать просто: `return` вместо `return None`.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо создания вложенной функции, иногда можно просто продублировать условие или флаг выставить или for/else синтаксис задействовать:

```
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        for q in c:
            if q == 400:
                break # inner loop
            print(i, j, q)
        else: # no break
            continue # middle loop
        break # middle loop
```

Вариант со вложенной функцией является более простым читаемым и компактным.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) можно внутренние два цикла объединить в один, тогда `break` будет "выходить" во внешний цикл:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

for i in a:
    for j, q in product(b, c):
        if q == 400:
            print("break")
            break
        print(i, j, q)
```

Вывод:

```
1 10 100
1 10 200
1 10 300
break
2 10 100
2 10 200
2 10 300
break
3 10 100
3 10 200
3 10 300
break
4 10 100
4 10 200
4 10 300
break
5 10 100
5 10 200
5 10 300
break
```